# problems with tk calendar catching

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

i need to know how to catch the output of a dateentry function. when i choose a date he prints correct date but i cant get the return value and put it in the cleaningschedule function..

```
cal = DateEntry(master,selectmode='day', 
date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd",foreground='white',background='darkblue',borderwidt h=2,locale='nl')
cal.place(x =140,y=20)



def get_date(*args):
    dt=cal.get_date().strftime("%Y,%m,%d")
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y,%m,%d")
    print(dt)
    return end_date



cal.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>",lambda e: get_date())
startdate = get_date()
def starter():
    CleaningSchedule()
    master.after(2000, starter)     


def CleaningSchedule():
    global startdate, selector
    now = date.today()
    #master.withdraw()
    days_calc = int(date_count_field.get())
    target = startdate + timedelta(days=days_calc)
    print('Vandaag is het: ',now, 'Volgende ronde is: ', target)
    outputGui = 'Vandaag is het: ',now, 'Volgende ronde is: ', target

    output_label =Label(master, text=outputGui)
    output_label.place(y=380,x=10)  
    
    if target == now:
        startdate += timedelta(days=days_calc)
        target += timedelta(days=days_calc)
```

Comment: Simply use `startdate = cal.get_date()` (need to add `global startdate`) inside `get_date()`.  Don't need to convert it to `datetime.datetime` object.

Comment: nope same issue it needs to count from the date that i choose, but he thakes always the date today..

Comment: It works for me with the changes I suggested.  It is better to update your question with a [mre].